# whitespace-line-column highlight basing on the column number instead of char count

Tags: org-mode, whitespace-mode

config

```
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-line-column 80) ;; limit line length
(setq whitespace-style '(face tabs empty trailing lines-tail))
```

[image: reference image]

For first line, whitespace-mode correctly highlights characters in line which are over 80 characters

In second line, org symbol (\Rightarrow) is used. whitespace-mode seems to highlight based on the character count instead of column number 80

Need help in making whitespace-mode highlight basing on the column number instead of character count.. or any better alternatives... Thanks

edit:

evaluation `(current-column)` at the location of first highlighted(pink) `l` in first line gives 80

evaluating `(current-column)` at the location of first highlighted(pink) arrow in second line gives 16

Comment: It would be helpful if you could please evaluate `(current-column)` at the location of the first pink arrow and add that result to your question with an edit.  That way we can elaborate (or disprove) the stated hypothesis that:  "*whitespace-mode seems to highlight based on the character count instead of column number 80.*"   One idea you may wish to explore is using the actual ascii character `⇒` instead of `\Rightarrow`.

Comment: updated the requested info..I have the same issue with other org mode symbols (https://orgmode.org/worg/org-symbols.html) too.. If you are referring to copy pasting the ascii character, it would be difficult to incorporate in my work flow.. any other ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated..